# Parent child Hover not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML like this where inner is the child div and outer is the parent div.

**What I have to achieve** : activate that div which has mouse over it.

I have called the hover function of the jQuery and it is helping me to  append  and remove the active class.

**The problem**: when I move the cursor upto innerchild div,it is activated but slowly when I move the cursor out from inner div to the outer parent div, the outer is not activated.

I tracked the mouse movement too.  **https://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/zaz1qh8e/2/** .

**The result**: the mouseout of outer div is not fired when the inner div is hover

```js
 $('div').hover(
   function() {
     $('div').removeClass('activeHover');
     $(this).addClass('activeHover');
   },
   function() {
     $(this).removeClass('activeHover');
   }
 );
```

```css
.outer {
  background-color: #aeaeae;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.inner {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.activeHover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are hovering the child you are also hovering the parent...did you consider that?

Comment: Yes, @Paulie_D . I have that in mind. I also tried to unbind all the  hover events on child hover, but that also didn't work. I am going with my requirement pal. Do you think I am asking impossible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to achieve this, you need to listen to the `mousemove` event too.
Also, I added `event.stopPropagation();` so when you hover or move in the `.inner` div, the events of the `.outer` will not fired.

```js
$('div').bind({
  mouseenter: eve,
  mousemove: eve,
  mouseout: function() {
    $(this).removeClass('activeHover');
  }
});

function eve(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('div').removeClass('activeHover');
  $(this).addClass('activeHover');
}
```

```css
.outer {
  background-color: #aeaeae;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.inner {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.activeHover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man! I actually needed that. Well i haven't thought of  mouse move. Thanks man

Comment: hello Mosh! , can you help me with this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551847/track-only-mouse-move-of-hovered-child-element-in-a-nested-div-tag

Comment: I saw that you already got an answer. In the future, you can contact me via my linkedin profile (you can see it in my profile page)

Answer (score 2):

I tried separate functions for mouseover and mouseleave with jquery and is working for me. Could you please try this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.inner').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass('activeHover');
    $('.outer').removeClass('activeHover');
  });
  $('.outer').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass('activeHover');
    $('.inner').removeClass('activeHover');
  });
  $('.inner').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('activeHover');
    $('.outer').addClass('activeHover');
  });
  $('.outer').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.outer').removeClass('activeHover');
  });
});
```

```css
.outer {
  background-color: #aeaeae;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.inner {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.activeHover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
</div>

<ul class="mousemovement">

</ul>
```